# JPA - Change table at runtime

Tags: java, orm, jpa, openjpa

Tables
    sales_2009
    sales_2008
    sales_2007

And only one class (sales), How change the table at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

> How change the table at runtime?

That's not supported out-of-the-box by standard JPA. But implementation might provide extensions for [Horizontal partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29):

- Hibernate has [Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html).
- EclipseLink has [a SessionBroker feature](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=126323&#page_top).
- OpenJPA has a [Slice plug-in](http://people.apache.org/~ppoddar/slice/site/).

I can't say anything about the maturity of Slice.

An alternative solution would be to define three different persistence units and to map the `Sales` entity specifically in each of them (possibly using XML mappings to reuse the Java code). And then, obtain the "right" `EntityManager` from the appropriate `EntityManagerFactory`. This solution is not ideal from a memory point of view though (plus some other limitations).

#### See also

- [News: Slice: OpenJPA for distributed persistence](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=48000)
- [Slice: OpenJPA for distributed persistence](http://groups.google.com/group/hibernate-shards-dev/browse_thread/thread/a1bf86180f6ecf63)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I solved with `iBATIS`

In the file map (xml) 
`select * from $table$ where date = #date# and product_id = #product_id#`

*In the file Java - example with Servlet:-

```
Map parameter = new HashMap(); 
parameter.put("table", "sales2009");
parameter.put("date", "2009-10-08"); //MySQL date :) 
parameter.put("product_id",17);

SqlMapClient sqlMap = (SqlMapClient) getServletContext().getAttribute("sqlMap");

List result = sqlMap.queryForList("selectSalesByParameters",parameter); 
for(Sales s : result) { }
```

**Important:** `$table$ != #table` is not working.